# Where do adverbs go when the verb is sent to the end?

Tags: adverb

So in German if I want to say:

> One can see the area better.

I get the basic part of

> Man kann die Gegend sehen.

But I don't know where to put the adverb. 
Is it after the first verb:

> Man kann besser die Gegend sehen.

or next to the second verb:

> Man kann die Gegend besser sehen.

or maybe somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions are possible, but the version where the adverb is placed near the infinite verb at the end of the sentence, is more common. The difference is the focus that you put on the sentence:

Focus on *Gegend*:

> Was kann man besser sehen? Die Häuser, den Wald oder die Gegend?
>   Man kann besser die Gegend sehen.
>
> What can you see better? The houses, the forest or the area?
>   One can better see the area.

Focus on *sehen*:

> Was kann man hier mit der Gegend besser machen? Sehen, hören oder schmecken?
>   Man kann die Gegend besser sehen.
>
> What can you do better with the area? See, hear or taste?
>   One can see the area better.

Answer (score 2):

In most situations you would pair the adverb with the verb that it is modifying.

> Man kann die Gegend besser sehen.